# Tunnel or SSL Forbidden

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I get this error. Something wrong with the proxy setup, though I can download software updates in eclipse with the same settings, but am not able to push my commits to github. [image]

Comment: What kind of proxy configuration do you use? ssh is usually not done via proxy...

Comment: I'm behind an office firewall..so its a DNS entry for proxy and is a HTTP/HTTPS proxy!

Answer (score 0):

Github allows you to access a repository with [different protocols](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use).

If a https proxy is your only way outside you should use an https url to access you repository.
Just replace the `ssh://` with `https://` and you should be fine.